# Trying to do a app with a simple button that leads to a website on unity

Tags: android, url, button, unity-game-engine, web

i´m trying to make a simple app for a school project with unity.
The design is complete, but the buttons are not working as i want them to.
I want them to open the browser and a website when i click them.
I wrote a code like shown in a couple of forums but it´s still not working.
How can i link the button to the Script correctly?
Could someone please help me?

The script:

```
using System;
```

using UnityEngine;

public class MensaplanButtonLink : MonoBehaviour {

```
private void buttonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.facebook.com");
}
```

}

Comment: First add a Debug.Log("Button was Pressed"); to the method, and see if it's called at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   public void OpenURL()
{
 Application.OpenURL("google.com/"); //Your link
}`
```

`Add function to button Onclick event.

Comment: now it is accepting the code but it is still not working

Comment: Add function via inspector on button OnClick event.

Comment: it is not working when i build Android app.